# Why is other parts of my mesh that I'm not painting over changing color in Texture Paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting

[image: Coloration issue]

For demonstration purposes I've painted over the face in dark blue, and other parts of my mesh have also changed color such as the upper torso and sides of the neck.

Not sure what's causing this, I presume that I've gone wrong somewhere while modeling.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Did you UV unwrap your mesh? You should give more information about your settings. also include more images, the more, the better.

Comment: t looks as if you have a UV map with overlapping islands, please show us the UV map , and  any shader tree depending on it, indicating which image you are painting into.. Best of all share a representative chunk of your file on https://blend-exchange.com/.